# Android ExoPlayer ConcatenatingMediaSource automatically play the next event where to get?

Tags: android, exoplayer

```
extractorMediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource[list.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    extractorMediaSource[i] = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(list.get(i).getMusicBean().getPath()), 
    dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
}

concatenatingMediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(extractorMediaSource);
concatenatingMediaSource.releaseSource();
loopingMediaSource = new LoopingMediaSource(concatenatingMediaSource);
mSimpleExoPlayer.prepare(loopingMediaSource);
```

I would like to know, `ConcatenatingMediaSource` automatically play the next event where to get?

Comment: what `"where to get"`? what do you mean?

Comment: Resolved ！[link](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2908)